# Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token) while making app

Tags: java, xml, compiler-errors

I'm bit new to Eclipse. I'm making an app. But, when compiling, i got an error (like title says). Here's the XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<values
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android
  <ImageView android:gravity="center" android:id="@id/app_icon" android:scaleType="centerCrop" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
  <TextView android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge" android:textColor="?android:textColorPrimary" android:ellipsize="end" android:gravity="center" android:id="@id/app_name" android:paddingLeft="6.0dip" android:paddingRight="6.0dip" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:singleLine="true" android:layout_toRightOf="@id/app_icon" android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
  <nine-patch android:src="@drawable/activity_title_bar" android:dither="true"/>
</values>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<values xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android
```

should be

```
<values xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
```

Comment: Oh yeah it's much nicer than wrapping around ``. Thanks

Comment: Yes. But there is a trick to it.  I added the XML tag to provide hints to the formatter.  Lacking that tag, we'd need to precede the snippet with `<!-- language: lang-xml -->` to get it to render correctly.  (whispers)  And your example still shows `<values <values` ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
<values
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android
```

Should be:

```
<values
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew Thompson for the answer. Solved !